# Attendance get classes whose attendance not submitted

Tags: php, laravel

Creating Attendance system in laravel where need to check the classes for which attendance is submitted and which classes pending. Students data is saved in students table.

At the time of attendance the class whose attendance is submitted are saved in **attendence_dates** table. (To check which day for which class is working and data final submitted or not)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('attendence_dates', function (Blueprint $table) {                  
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->date('date')->default(date("Y-m-d"));
        $table->string('clas_name', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('section_name',20)->nullable();
        $table->boolean('working')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('final')->default(false);
        $table->string('remarks', 100)->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('updated_by')
          ->nullable(); 
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')
           ->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
    });
}
```

And the **Attendances** table where the attendance of students are saved with P AND A status.

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('attendences', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('att_month')->default('0')->nullable();
            $table->date('att_date')->useCurrent();            
            $table->string('clas_name', 20)->nullable();
            $table->string('section_name',20)->nullable();                           
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('student_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('acc_id')->nullable();
            $table->enum('status', ['P', 'A'])->default('P');                
            $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')
                    ->onDelete('SET NULL')
                    ->onUpdate('CASCADE'); // SET NULL, CASCADE, RESTRICT, DO NOTHING, NO ACTION
            $table->foreign('acc_id')->references('acc_id')->on('students')
                    ->onDelete('SET NULL')
                    ->onUpdate('CASCADE');                                         
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

used this code to fetch all existing classes and sections from 'students' table.

```
$classAll   = DB::table('students')
    ->select('clas_name', 'section_name')
    ->groupBy('clas_name','section_name')
    ->orderBy('clas_name','ASC')
    ->orderBy('section_name','ASC')
    ->get();
```

And this to fetch classes and sections whose attendance is submitted.

```
// FETCH POSTED CLASSES DATA
$posted = DB::table('attendence_dates')
        ->select('clas_name', 'section_name')
        ->where('date', $date)
        ->groupBy('clas_name','section_name')
        ->orderBy('clas_name','ASC')
        ->orderBy('section_name','ASC')
        ->get();
```

Now have to show the pending classes i.e. classes which not submitted.
I am learning laravel, from search and documentation i got this collection function.
tried  **`$pending = $classAll->diff($posted);`** but its giving error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string ".

Also tried **`$pending = $classAll->diffKeys($posted);`**
its not giving any error, but not getting desired results. Total count is reduced but not exact classes removed from total.

I want to get the classes and sections which attendance not submitted on particular date. If there is any function available in laravel or query to get the desired result.

*** As asked for further explanation, Class And Sections table included in question
P.S. I want to further explain that why i am fetching classes from students table instead of class and section table. There may be some empty classes in class table and some classes may have 5 (A,B,C,D,E) sections but some may have 2(A,B) or 3 sections. So I am saving class names and sections in students table & directly loading classes from students table.

**Class Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('class', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('full_name', 50);
        $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();        
    });
}
```

Sections Table

```
 public function up()

    {
        Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id',true,true);
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->string('short_name', 50); 
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: @nnichols Classes and Sections have separate tables having id and relationship with students table. But in Attendance system intentionally used names instead of ids so that if student class or section changed then previous attendance remain intact.

Comment: @nnichols i think that was irrelevant to the question, have class  and sections table but they may have some empty classes too, i want to load only classes where students added. so i am directly loading classed and sections from students table.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not interested in doing it properly at the database layer, just use [array_udiff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) to compare the two arrays. I am not very familiar with Laravel, so I am assuming that `$classAll` and `$posted` are arrays of objects:

```php
$pending = array_udiff($classAll, $posted, function($a, $b) {
    if (
        $a->clas_name === $b->clas_name &&
        $a->section_name === $b->section_name
    ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
});
```

---

I am leaving my previous answer here as it still shows a better approach to the scenario.

As you have not included the `classes` and `sections` tables in your question, this assumes that you have:

- classes (id, name)
- sections (id, name, class_id)

One way to get the classes/sections with attendance not submitted for a given date:

```sql
SELECT
    c.name AS clas_name,
    s.name AS section_name
FROM classes c
JOIN sections s ON c.id = s.class_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM attendance_dates
        WHERE clas_name = c.name
        AND section_name = s.name
        AND date = :specific_date
)
ORDER BY clas_name, section_name;
```

With Laravel's Query Builder it should be something like this:

```php
$classesNotSubmitted = DB::table('classes c')
    ->join('sections s', 'c.id', '=', 's.class_id')
    ->select('c.name clas_name', 's.name section_name')
    ->whereNotExists(function($query) {
            $query->selectRaw(1)
                  ->from('attendance_dates')
                  ->whereRaw('clas_name = c.name')
                  ->whereRaw('section_name = s.name')
                  ->where('date', $date)
        })
    ->orderBy('clas_name', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('section_name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

If you want to get the full list of classes/sections and whether attendance was submitted for a given date you could move the subquery into the `SELECT` list:

```sql
SELECT
    c.name AS clas_name,
    s.name AS section_name,
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM attendance_dates
        WHERE clas_name = c.name
        AND section_name = s.name
        AND date = :specific_date
    ) AS att_taken
FROM classes c
JOIN sections s ON c.id = s.class_id
ORDER BY clas_name, section_name;
```

With Laravel's Query Builder:

```php
$classesAll = DB::table('classes c')
    ->join('sections s', 'c.id', '=', 's.class_id')
    ->selectRaw('c.name clas_name, s.name section_name, EXISTS (
                                        SELECT 1
                                        FROM attendance_dates
                                        WHERE clas_name = c.name
                                        AND section_name = s.name
                                        AND date = ?) AS att_taken', [$date])
    ->orderBy('class_name', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('section_name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

I am not a Laravel user and these have not been tested, so may need tweaking to get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run a query to get all the names of the classes that are not present in a certain date in the attendance_date table.
It could be like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE clas_name NOT IN (
    SELECT clas_name
    FROM attendance_date
    WHERE date = <your date>
);
```

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for laravel method to find and delete matching data from two collections.